# configuring spark-1.6.0 on centOS6.3

Tags: apache-spark, hive

I am trying to configure hive-0.9.0 on spark1.6.0. Is it possible to do that.?? Or please let me know, where am I incorrect??

While going through certain configuration pages on the Internet, I came across few things, please help me understand this:

"Install/build a compatible version.  Hive root pom.xml's  defines what version of Spark it was built/tested with."

Thanks for help in advance...

Comment: What do you mean by *"configure Hive on Spark"*? Do you want to run a Spark job with SparkSQL access to a Hive table? Or do you want to run a Hive query with Sparke as "execution engine"?

Comment: PS: remember that Hive 0.9 is almost 4 years old. Current Apache version is Hive 1.2 -- er, actually it's 2.0!

Comment: Thanks Samson. I am now trying with Hive 1.2.1. I need Spark to access Hive tables. Spark is starting but not able to find Hive metastore.

Comment: Make sure that the CLASSPATH contains two **directories**: the one with core Hadoop conf, and the one with Hive conf, e.g. `export CLASSPATH=/etc/hadoop/conf:/etc/hive/conf:$CLASSPATH`

Comment: thanks but I have done certain things regarding configuration. These r the errors:

16/03/03 15:21:10 INFO DataNucleus.Persistence: Property hive.metastore.integral.jdo.pushdown unknown - will be ignored
16/03/03 15:21:10 INFO DataNucleus.Persistence: Property datanucleus.cache.level2 unknown - will be ignored
16/03/03 15:21:10 WARN metadata.Hive: Failed to access metastore. This class should not accessed in runtime.
org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.HiveException: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.SessionHiveMetaStoreClient

Comment: looks like spark is unable to see hive's metastore...